# How can I verify that a futures broker is legitimate?

Tags: united-states, futures, brokerage, online-brokerage

To verify that a stock brokerage firm is legitimate and not a scam, I can use FINRA's [BrokerCheck](https://brokercheck.finra.org). Some stock brokers helpfully provide a link to BrokerCheck in the fine print at the bottom of web pages.

I am now looking at some futures brokers, and when I try to look up the futures brokers on BrokerCheck, I get no results. My question is: how can I verify that a futures broker is legitimate? Is there an official place where the legitimacy of a futures broker can be checked in much the same way as how the legitimacy of a stock broker can be checked using FINRA's BrokerCheck?

Comment: Unless they are well-known household names, don't spend 1 second on it.  Brokers are nothing - just use the biggest most famous 2 or 3 !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.cftc.gov/check

> The Commodity Exchange Act requires certain firms and individuals to
> be registered with the CFTC.  Registration and examination of
> intermediaries is conducted **on behalf of** the CFTC by the National
> Futures Association (NFA) under the supervision of the CFTC.

https://www.nfa.futures.org/registration-membership/index.html

> The Commodity Exchange Act (CEA) requires certain firms and
> individuals that conduct business in the derivatives industry to
> register with the CFTC. CFTC regulations also require, with few
> exceptions, CFTC registered firms to be NFA Members. The CFTC has
> **delegated** registration responsibility to NFA.

You can search at https://www.nfa.futures.org/basicnet/